# C# Object Serialization Changes

Tags: c#

I have the following issue:

My object is being serialized as follows:

```
MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(memorystream, _policy);
CaptureData = Convert.ToBase64String(memorystream.ToArray());
```

And then saved to my database and de-serialized as required from the data saved in the database.

My problem now is that I can't make changes to this object, add properties etc as this breaks the deserialization.

Any suggestions on how I can add properties without breaking serialization of previous objects?

Comment: Add property to class, create new class as old class, deserialize data as new create class object then mat to you changed object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible using this serializer.

If possible, use another serializer that deals with backward compatibility like [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

Comment: Do you know whether protobuf is compatible with CSLA objects?

Comment: I don't know; protobuf-net works as most serializer : it serializes / deserialize objects to / from a stream. The only restriction is that this object is an instance of class generated by the .proto file

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`[OptionalField]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.optionalfieldattribute.aspx) and similar to take advantage of the [version tolerant serialisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) built into .Net.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift from the built-in serialization , as this is, as you saw, is rigid and not scallable. Pick any other serializaiton technique that let's you maintan scallability of your types and flexibility of your system.

- custom binary serialization
- xml serialization
- json serialization
- binary serialization with protobuf (just example...)

All this, if you *can* do that. If not, for some architectural (historical) restrictions, just can do something like suggested in Hamlet's comment. But it sounds like a rough solution to me.